How to present a view with partial screen width on iPad and dismiss on background tap
I'm currently refactoring my iPad app from UIKit to SwiftUI and need help replicating a specific view presentation behavior.
Current Implementation:
I have a SwiftUI view (AccountDetailsView) that is presented from a UIKit view controller (HomeViewController) using UIHostingController. The AccountDetailsView takes up 2/3 of the view controller's width from the right side, and the remaining 1/3 of the screen is transparent. When the transparent area is tapped, the view dismisses. This is achieved by setting the transitioningDelegate and using a custom transition.
Refactoring:
I'm now refactoring HomeViewController to HomeView using SwiftUI and want to replicate the same behavior that AccountDetailsView should act like custom modal view.

let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: AccountDetailsView())
let size = CGSize(width: (view.bounds.width * 2 / 3).rounded(), height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)

controller.preferredContentSize = size
controller.view.backgroundColor = .clear
controller.transitioningDelegate = SlideTransitioningController(direction: .right)
controller.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
present(controller, animated: true)

Here's a SlideTransitioningController implementation if it helps:
import UIKit

public final class SlideTransitioningController: NSObject, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

  var direction: PresentationDirection
  var backgroundType: BackgroundType
  var dismissOnTapOutside: Bool

  public init(
    direction: PresentationDirection = .left,
    background: BackgroundType = .blacked,
    dismissOnTapOutside: Bool = true
  ) {
    self.direction = direction
    self.backgroundType = background
    self.dismissOnTapOutside = dismissOnTapOutside
  }

  // MARK: - UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate
  public func presentationController(
    forPresented presented: UIViewController,
    presenting: UIViewController?,
    source: UIViewController
  ) -> UIPresentationController? {
    SlideInPresentationController(
      presentedViewController: presented,
      presenting: presenting,
      direction: direction,
      backgroundType: backgroundType,
      dismissOnTapOutside: dismissOnTapOutside
    )
  }

  public func animationController(
    forPresented presented: UIViewController,
    presenting: UIViewController,
    source: UIViewController
  ) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    SlideInPresentationAnimator(direction: direction, isPresentation: true)
  }

  public func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    SlideInPresentationAnimator(direction: direction, isPresentation: false)
  }
}

// MARK: - Types
public extension SlideTransitioningController {
  enum PresentationDirection: Equatable {
    case left, top, right, bottom, center
  }

  enum BackgroundType {
    case blurred, blacked
  }
}


One approach is to embed your SwiftUI view within a UIKit UIHostingController, where you can add UIKit-specific features. After that, you can convert the UIHostingController back to a SwiftUI view using UIViewControllerRepresentable.
Here’s an implementation example for reference:
class SlideTransitionWrapper<Content: View>: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

private let content: () -> Content
var onDismiss: (() -> Void)?
var hostVC: UIHostingController<Content>?
private lazy var slideTransitioningController = SlideTransitioningController(direction: .right, onDismiss: onDismiss)

required init?(coder: NSCoder) { fatalError("") }

init(content: @escaping () -> Content) {
    self.content = content
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

func show() {
    guard hostVC == nil else { return }
    let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: content())
    let size = CGSize(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 2 / 3).rounded(),
                      height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)

    controller.preferredContentSize = size
    controller.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    controller.transitioningDelegate = slideTransitioningController
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
    hostVC = controller
    controller.presentationController?.delegate = self
    present(controller, animated: true)
}

func hide() {
    guard let vc = hostVC, !vc.isBeingDismissed else { return }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    hostVC = nil
}

func presentationControllerWillDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) {
    hostVC = nil
    onDismiss?()
  }
}

struct SlideTransitionRepresentable<Content: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
@Binding var show: Bool
let content: () -> Content

func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<SlideTransitionRepresentable<Content>>)
-> SlideTransitionWrapper<Content> {
    let vc = SlideTransitionWrapper(content: content)
    vc.onDismiss = {
        vc.hostVC = nil
        show = false
    }
    return vc
}

func updateUIViewController(
    _ uiViewController: SlideTransitionWrapper<Content>,
    context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<SlideTransitionRepresentable<Content>>
) {
    show ? uiViewController.show() : uiViewController.hide()
  }
}

extension View {
    public func slideTransition<Content: View>(
        isPresented: Binding<Bool>,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content
    ) -> some View {
        background(SlideTransitionRepresentable(show: isPresented, content: content))
    }
}

And usage of it be will be like below:
.slideTransition(isPresented: $showSlideTransitioningView) {
      YourView()
}


Wow, you’re amazing! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much for your hard work and help.
